# Cannot install pysftp paramiko python

Tags: python, paramiko, pysftp

If I try to install the above packages using `setup.py install`. I get 
download error on https://pypi.python.org/simple/ecdsa:

> timed out -- Some packages may not be found!
>       Error:could not find suitable distribution for requirement.parse('ecdsa>=0.11')

Comment: It seems, that you have a network issue. Can you open https://pypi.python.org/simple/ecdsa in a browser?

Comment: yeap i can open in browser, am sure no network issue.

Comment: Obviously it is a network/connectivity issue, because you get `timed out` error. Do you use proxy?

Comment: how do i dodge proxy? but the browser should also have given same error rit?

Answer (score 0):

The Timeout error you are getting is because of a network error.

Try this from your setup.py directory

```
sudo env http_proxy=proxyserverAddress:port setup.py install
```